# PHP - Como puedo incluir un botón para agregar archivos en formato .zip -.rar - .jpg?

Tags: php

Necesito incluir en mi página web un botón que me permita escoger archivos de formato .zip, .rar y .jpg para subir.

A continuación les dejo el código de lo que llevo:
    
                            Adjuntar documento* 
                            
                                        
                     
                    ****Es obligatorio adjuntar un archivo para avanzar, el archivo DEBE SER RAR,ZIP O JPG****
                      
                            
                      
    php

```
  $target_path = "carpeta para guardar"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
        if (!file_exists($target_path)) {
          mkdir($target_path, 0777, true);


        }

        $target_path = $target_path . "Adjunto_pruebaNOK_id_$last_id" . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image



                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['documento']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder


                echo "<script>alert($j. ')Archivo subido satisfactoriamente!', 'Archivo subido correctemante')</script>";
                  echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Archivo subido satisfactoriamente!.</span><br/><br/>';
                  //
                    echo "<script>alert('Archivo subido satisfactoriamente!.', 'Adjunto OK')</script>"; 

                  //echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
                    echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;url=$yourURL'/>"; 





        } else {//if file was not moved.


                  echo $j. ').<span id="error">Error... Por favor intentar nuevamente! </span><br/><br/>';

            }
```